# Python Pandas to_csv method formatting

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I create a 2D matrix using PANDAS with the following code:

```
def constructTransition(originalList):

st = np.ones((26, 26))
s1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
      'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
s2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
      'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
stateProbability = pd.DataFrame(st, index=s1, columns=s2)

    # FILLING the matrix


stateProbability.to_csv("StateProbability.csv", sep='\t', float_format='%.12f')
```

This is working fine except that it prints like this:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
a   0.000138370001  0.009685900097  0.100733361007  0.013421890134  0.088695170887  0.018403210184  0.028227480282  0.179465891795  0.051335270513  0.000553480006  0.000276740003  0.049121350491  0.111111111111  0.042617960426  0.011484710115  0.031686730317  0.000138370001  0.087449840874  0.025736820257  0.063096720631  0.021308980213  0.019371800194  0.028227480282  0.007887090079  0.001522070015  0.008302200083
b   0.354294478528  0.007668711656  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.035276073620  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.013803680982  0.116564417178  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.070552147239  0.001533742331  0.250000000000  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.019938650307  0.004601226994  0.003067484663  0.087423312883  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.001533742331  0.015337423313  0.001533742331
c   0.116357504216  0.000562113547  0.021922428331  0.000843170320  0.209949409781  0.001686340641  0.000281056773  0.000281056773  0.229342327150  0.000281056773  0.000281056773  0.001967397414  0.000281056773  0.116638560989  0.137436762226  0.000281056773  0.000281056773  0.021641371557  0.044406970208  0.009836987071  0.061270376616  0.000281056773  0.000281056773  0.005340078696  0.017987633502  0.000281056773
d   0.080699774266  0.000282167043  0.000282167043  0.007054176072  0.274830699774  0.000282167043  0.000282167043  0.000282167043  0.085214446953  0.000282167043  0.005079006772  0.094525959368  0.000282167043  0.327313769752  0.069413092551  0.000282167043  0.000282167043  0.033013544018  0.000282167043  0.000564334086  0.015237020316  0.000282167043  0.003103837472  0.000282167043  0.000282167043  0.000282167043
e   0.000121824938  0.049582749589  0.040263141865  0.047146250838  0.028811597734  0.015776329415  0.023329475544  0.164768228056  0.041055003959  0.001522811720  0.013339830663  0.063653529878  0.041055003959  0.050435524152  0.003837485533  0.034110982518  0.000060912469  0.120972163002  0.062800755315  0.082901870013  0.009563257599  0.067491015411  0.028628860328  0.001827374063  0.002862886033  0.004081135408
...
...
```

As you can see the letters correspond to the columns are not tab delimited and thy are not in the center of their corresponding column.
How can I force the "HEADERS" to be in the center of the columns?

Comment: why do you need it in the CSV file? if you want to have it nicely printed - just print it

Comment: no specific reason to be in CSV format. maybe  as you said i just print it to a file normally. but is there anyway to format the headers? (thanks for asking the correct question)

Comment: There's really no way to view it aesthetically pleasing (at least not in a text program), though you could render the columns as 'centered' if you opened it with a spreadsheet program and specify the delimiters as tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 99)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '%.12f')
```

then just print your DF:

```
print(df)

n [34]: stateProbability
ut[34]:
              a              b              c              d              e              f              g              h              i
    j              k              l              m              n              o              p              q              r              s
         t              u              v              w              x              y              z
 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456
89012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.1
3456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012
 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456
89012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.1
3456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012
 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456
89012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.1
3456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012
 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456
89012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.1
3456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012 0.123456789012
```